# TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, data-mining

`here when i run the code , i face with the type error like :
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.

i check line by line so the error is occur in this bellow line of code.

```
plt.contourf(x1, x2, classifier.predict(np.array([x1.ravel(), x2.ravel()]).T).reshape(x1.shape),
alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('purple','green' )))
```

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]

Comment: "i check line by line so the error is occur in this bellow line of code." why don't you just post the full error message including the stack trace... that would tell us **exactly** where the error is occuring. But again, you really should provide a [mcve]